# Problem in second and third author using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

My code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear, dashed=false,maxcitenames=2,giveninits]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{last-first} 
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{last-first}
```

and referencing:

```
@inproceedings{kazem2003design,
  title={Design considerations for a background auditory display to aid pilot situation awareness},
  author={Kazem, Mandana LN and Noyes, Janet M and Lieven, Nicholas J},
  year={2003},
  organization={Georgia Institute of Technology}
}
```

The outcome:

[image]

It supposes to be:

```
Kazem, M.L., Noyes, J.M. and Lieven, N.J., 2003. Design considerations for a background auditory display to aid pilot situation awareness. Georgia Institute of Technology.
```

where the order of the first name and last name for the second author and the third author is not working well.

(Second author) `J. M. Noyes` --> `Noyes, J.M.`
(Third authro) `N.J. Lieven` --> `Lieven, N.J.`

Comment: Please don't post code fragments, but instead post a compilable document that people can play with.  But this question itself is a duplicate of [lastname and firstname initials in biblatex bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/464740).

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks. it working.

Comment: `style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` is equivalent to the shorter `style=authoryear,`. `nameyeardelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter now and so `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` would be nicer as `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`. The name format `last-first` is now called `family-given`: `\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given}`, but you probably want `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` in which case you can remove the two lines about `editor` and `translator`.